# Alamofire “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire in my project. But I'm not using it with cocoapods. I just drag and dropped it in my project as shown in Alamofire Github tutorial.

Now I'm facing an issue that while compiling the project it's showing:

> "alamofire “info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file".

I've tried deleting derived data and everything which was shown in web.

Please give me solution for this.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T YELL. Please edit your question by removing all of the unnecessary caps lock.

Comment: Sorry for that... But it's a keyboard mistake....

Answer (score 0):

Don't drag and drop the  Alamofire.xcodeproj into the Project Navigator of your application's Xcode project. 
Just add the Alamofire.xcodeproj by right click on your project and that in your project and rest follow as it is in Alamofire GitHub tutorial. 
If you drag and drop that into your Xcode Project, sometimes it's not copying all the files from that.